# Getting the ID (PK) of a newly persisted entity

Tags: mysql, servlets, persistence, jpa-2.0

I'm developing a J2EE 6 Web Application, using a MySql 5.02 DataBase. I'm trying to generate a hash digest of the ID, every time I create a new Entity. This is set to a column on the Table.

But well, I'm stuck on something that is apparently easy, and according with what I found googling, possible. Basically I want to retrieve the ID (Primary Key) of a newly persisted object, but whatever I try, it returns null.

The steps are follow are:

1. Create the Instance of the Entity -> `userCard = new Users();`
2. Setting the corresponding fields with some values.
3. Calling the `persist()` method of the `EntityManager`.

After reading some forums, I understood I had to either call `flush()` after `persist()`, or use `merge()` and use the returned entity to retrieve the id.

```
public void createAndFlush(Users users) {
    em.persist(users);
    em.flush();
}

public Integer edit(Users users) {
    return ((Users)em.merge(users)).getIdvcards();
}
```

None of them (among some other combinations) work, well, the Entity is successfully persisted, but the ID field returns null.

These are the correspinding annotations of the id column I want to retrieve:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "idvcards")
private Integer idvcards;
```

And obviously, the column idvcards of my table is set to Auto-Increment and Primary Key.

Maybe I just need to clarify my Peristence-Management concepts, but I'd appreciate if I can get some hint to solve this basic issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe is not the most elegant solution ever, but finally I succeded on retrieving the ID of the new Entity:

```
public Integer create(User user) {
    em.persist(users);
    em.flush();
    return (Integer) em.getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil().getIdentifier(users);
}
```

And well, althought is not related to the functionality, I changed the entity name to the singular form as @Bohemian suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
```

Also, I don't use the value returned from `merge`. I just `persist` then `flush` and the entity object magically gets the new key value.

p.s. Tables should never be named in the plural, and especially not the entity class. Call the class `User` (and the table if you can). Otherwise it's just confusing: `Users` sounds like a collection of `User`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and the piece of Advice (I agree on the fact that Entities should be named in the singular form), but unfortunately without the `strategy` property, `persist()` throws a `DatabaseException`. It seems to try to find a table called "sequence", which I guess would be necessary to define the sequence, since I'm not declaring a `GenerationType`.

Answer (score 0):

It will work fine

```
em.persist(usmApproveTransaction);
em.flush();

System.out.println("++++++e++++++++"+usmApproveTransaction.getUatApproveTransIdPk());
return usmApproveTransaction;
```

I'm getting id using `em.flush();` after `persist`

> ++++++e++++++++51472